# I cannot remove the class "arrow-open" when clicked on the opened arrow again

Tags: jquery, html

I need to add the class "arrow-open" on  after the click on "has-child".
and remove when clicked on other siblings of "has-child". It works till that but doesn't remove it, when I click again on the active "has-child".

```
$('.has-child').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open-child');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('open-child');
    // remove classes from all
    $('.fa-angle-right').removeClass('arrow-open');
    // add class to the one we clicked
    $('.fa-angle-right', this).addBack(this).toggleClass('arrow-open');
});
```

This is the html

```
<div id="mobile-menu">
<ul class="mobile-nav">
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="has-child"><a href="#">Platform <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>
        <ul class="child-nav">
            <li><a href="hr.php">HR</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-child"><a href="#">Platform <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>
        <ul class="child-nav">
            <li><a href="hr.php">HR</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-child"><a href="#">Platform <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>
        <ul class="child-nav">
            <li><a href="hr.php">HR</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No I am not changing that, i just add one more class open-child to open the ul but the problem is that the angle inside it don't remove the class "arrow-open" when clicked on them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change order your script function like

```
$('.has-child').click(function() {
$(this).siblings().removeClass('open-child');
$(this).siblings().removeClass('arrow-open');
    $(this).toggleClass('open-child');

    // remove classes from all

    // add class to the one we clicked
    $('.fa-angle-right', this).addBack(this).toggleClass('arrow-open');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/kenjspot/3/

Comment: Hi this works but it has caused another issue that is when i click on other "has-child" element, the arrow class is not removed on the other or previously clicked elements.
can you have a look into this again please??

Comment: Thanks it is working. I was looking for something else but this worked just awesome.